# CakePHP Beginner: Advice needed, Everything on a single view or multi part forms

Tags: cakephp

Thanks in advance for any help offered and patience for my current web-coding experience.

Background:

I'm currently attempting to develop an web based application for my family's business.  There is a current version of this system I have developed in C#, however I want to get the system web-based and in the process learn cakephp and the MVC pattern.

Current problem:
I'm currently stuck in a controller that's supposed to take care of a PurchaseTicket.  This ticket will have an associated customer, line items, totals etc.  I've been trying to develop a basic 'add()' function to the controller however I'm having trouble with the following:

- I'm creating a view with everything on it: a button for searching customer, a button to add line items, and a save button.  Since I'm used to developing desktop applications, I'm thinking that I might be trying to transfer the same logic to web-based.  Is this something that would be recommended or do'able?

I'm running into basic problems like 'searching customer'.  From the New Ticket page I'm redirecting to the customer controller, searching and then putting result in session variable or posting it back, but as I continue my process with the rest of the required information, I'm ending up with a bit of "spaghetti" code. Should I do a multi part form? If I do I break the visual design of the application.

Right now I ended up instantiating my PurchaseTicket model and putting it in a session variable.  I did this to save intermediate data however I'm not sure if instantiating a Model is conforming to cakephp standards or MVC pattern.

I apologize for the length, this is my first post as a member.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

So it sounds like there's a few questions, all with pretty open-ended answers. I don't know if this will end up an answer as such, but it's more information than I could put in a comment, so here I go:

First and foremost, if you haven't already, I'd recommend doing the [CakePHP Blog Tutorial](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) to get familiar with Cake, before diving straight into a conversion of your existing desktop app.

Second, get familiar with [CakePHP's bake console](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html). It will save you a LOT of time if you use it to get started on the web version of your app.

I can't stress how important it is to get a decent grasp of MVC and CakePHP on a small project before trying to tackle something substantial.

Third, the UI for web apps is definitely different to desktop apps. In the case of CakePHP, nothing is 'running' permanently on the server. The entire CakePHP framework gets instantiated, and dies, with every single page request to the server. That can be a tricky concept when transitioning from desktop apps, where everything is stored in memory, and instances of objects can exist for as long as you want them to. With desktop apps, it's easier to have a user go and do another task (like searching for a customer), and then send the result back to the calling object, the instance of which will still exist. As you've found out, if you try and mimic this functionality in a web app by storing too much information in sessions, you'll quickly end up with spaghetti code.

You can use AJAX (google it if you don't already know about it) to update parts of a page only, and get a more streamlined UI, which it sounds like something you'll be needing to do. To get a general idea of the possibilities, you might want to take a look at [Bamboo Invoice](http://bambooinvoice.org/). It's not built with CakePHP, but it's built with CodeIgniter, which is another open source PHP MVC framework. It sounds like Bamboo Invoice has quite a few similar functionalities to what you're describing (an Invoice has line items, totals, a customer, etc), so it might help you to get an idea of how you should structure your interface - and if you want to dig into the source code, how you can achieve some of the things you want to do.

Bamboo Invoice uses Ajax to give the app a feel of 'one view with everything on it', which it sounds like you want.

Fourth, regarding the specific case of your Customer Search situation, storing stuff in a session variable probably isn't the way to go. You may well want to use an autocomplete field, which sends an Ajax request to server after each time a character is entered in the field, and displays the list list of suggestions / matching customers that the server sends back. See an example here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Implementing an autocomplete isn't totally straight forward, but there should be plenty of examples and tutorials all over the web.

Lastly, I obviously don't know what your business does, but have you looked into existing software that might work for you, before building your own? There's a lot of great, flexible web-based solutions, at very reasonable prices, for a LOT of the common tasks that businesses have. There might be something that gives you great results for much less time and money than it costs to build your own solution.

Either way, good luck, and enjoy CakePHP!

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I appreciate you taking your time to help me out here. I did do the blog tutorial which helped me grasp the basics of CakePHP, however I think my problem might be more with web development concepts and the MVC pattern.  On the AJAX side, I do want to use it in my project, however I want the application to work without javascript first.  Good call on the Bamboo project, I've already downloaded and added the project to my IDE, I'll be checking it out

Comment: My biggest "concept" to get right now I guess would be situations where searching related information as part of a larger object and trying to keep my code clean and object oriented where I can.

Comment: You may also want to check out the CakePHP Search plugin: https://github.com/CakeDC/search